# Trying to overlay videos with different start times

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay two videos with different start times, and mix together their audio tracks.

These input files are WebRTC recordings, and each contains a single audio or video track.

Inputs:

- `RTc0.webm`: audio, Opus 40k, start time 9.078 sec
- `RT5f.webm`: audio, Opus 40k, start time 1.262 sec
- `RT8c.mkv`: video, H.264, start time 9.078 sec
- `RTf7.mkv`: video, H.264, start time 1.298 sec

I want to draw these videos side-by-side and mix together their audio.

## First try, using `-copyts`

My initial thought was to use [`-copyts`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) and just allow everything to align using their shared common timecode.

My command line looks like:

```
ffmpeg \
    -copyts \
    -ss 224.1 -i RTc0.webm -t 60 \
    -ss 224.1 -i RT5f.webm -t 60 \
    -ss 224.1 -i RTf7.mkv -t 60 \
    -ss 224.1 -i RT8c.mkv -t 60 \
    -filter_complex "

        color=c=black:s=1280x480 [background]; 
        [2:v] scale=640x480 [left]; 
        [3:v] scale=640x480 [right]; 
        [background][left]       overlay       [background+left]; 
        [background+left][right] overlay=x=640 [vout]; 

        [1:a][0:a] amix [aout]

    "  -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 28 -c:a aac -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" -y \
    -f matroska combined.mkv
```

Running this, I get an output where the video is correct (one video starts at 0 sec, one starts 7 seconds later), but both audio tracks start at 0 sec. The expected behavior is one audio track starts at 0 secs and the other starts 7 seconds later synchronized with the second video track.

## Second try, using `-itsoffset` and `asetpts`

I also tried using `-itsoffset` to shift the video tracks. This worked but `-itsoffset` didn't do anything for my audio tracks. It had strange effects, sometimes putting it for one shifted them both in time.

```
ffmpeg \
    -ss 0.00000000 -itsoffset 0 -i RTf7.mkv -t 60 \
    -ss 0.00000000 -itsoffset 7.781 -i RT8c.mkv -t 60 \
    -ss 0.00000000 -itsoffset 7.816 -i RT5f.webm -t 60 \
    -ss 0.00000000 -itsoffset 0 -i RTc0.webm -t 60 \
    -filter_complex "

        color=c=black:s=1280x480 [background]; 
        [0:v] scale=640x480 [left]; 
        [1:v] scale=640x480 [right]; 
        [background][left]       overlay=shortest=1       [background+left]; 
        [background+left][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=640 [vout]; 
        [2:a][3:a] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest [aout]

    "  -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 28 -c:a aac -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" -y \
    -f matroska combined.mkv
```

I then tried using the [`asetpts` filter](https://superuser.com/a/1082498/347427) to shift the audio track to preserve alignment, but it didn't work. The command `asetpts=PTS+(7.816/TB)` was just ignored:

```
ffmpeg \
    -copyts \
    -ss 0 -i RTc0.webm -t 60 \
    -ss 0 -i RT5f.webm -t 60 \
    -ss 0 -itsoffset 0 -i RTf7.mkv -t 60 \
    -ss 0 -itsoffset 7.781 -i RT8c.mkv -t 60 \
    -filter_complex "

        color=c=black:s=1280x480 [background]; 
        [2:v] scale=640x480 [left]; 
        [3:v] scale=640x480 [right]; 
        [background][left]       overlay       [background+left]; 
        [background+left][right] overlay=x=640 [vout]; 

        [1:a] asetpts=PTS+(7.816/TB), [0:a] amix [aout]

    "  -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 28 -c:a aac -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" -y \
    -f matroska segment_0.mkv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The amix filter syncs all inputs to start at the same time. Way around is to skip the `-ss` for the audio inputs, apply `aresample=async=1,atrim=225.398` to each audio input and then amix those filtered streams.

`225.398` is `224.1+1.298` - your `ss` value + start time of the earlier starting video stream. I've used the video stream value since the corresponding audio starts earlier, so you may lose sync if you used its value.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Won't `atrim` just discard the first 225.3 seconds then start begin playing at t=0 in the output? I need to discard the first 225.3 seconds then start playing at t=7 seconds in the output, to match the start time of the second video stream.

Comment: For `RTc0.webm`, the 7 seconds after 225 will be silent.